# How to select multiple items from contextMenuStrip

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# winForm project that use a contextMenuStrip. I'm trying to figure out how to disable/override default behavior of allowing only one toolStripMenuItem at a time for selection. I've been working at this for the last 2 days and I'm making 0 progress.

Does anyone know of any links or how to do this?

Thanks in advance,
-DA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code I found in one of our projects that might just be what you're after.  It came out of a `MouseDown` handler.  I think the key is setting the `CheckOnClick` property on each `ToolStripMenuItem`, which then allows you to realize that in the `Closing` event and set `e.Cancel = true`:

```
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenuStrip mStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
            mStrip.Closing += new ToolStripDropDownClosingEventHandler(mStrip_Closing);

            foreach (Control cntrl in this.Controls)
            {
                ToolStripMenuItem itm = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                itm.Text = cntrl.Text;
                itm.CheckOnClick = true;
                itm.Checked = cntrl.Visible;

                mStrip.Items.Add(itm);
                mStrip.Show(this.PointToScreen(new Point(_mouseX, _mouseY)));
            }
        }

        private void mStrip_Closing(Object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked)
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

Comment: thx Don! that's a start!!! i can keep it open now but how do i implement multiple selection of items? do you have any advice?

Comment: hey don, i think i understand it now. my "checked" property allows me to select multiple items. THX!!!! i think i can handle it from here! i'm VERY grateful, i think this is what i'm trying to do!

Comment: I'm glad that's working for you.  Be sure to mark the answer so it can close.